# there is a problem in using Middleware api call in react typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios, react-typescript

this is a react-typescript project that uses middleware created with Axios to call Api anywhere in react component.

My App component is:

```
import React from "react";
import AllRiders from "./components/AllRiders";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AllRiders />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my middleware structure
Constants file is :

```
const BASE_URL = "https://do-rider.cheetay.pk";

export const END_POINTS = {
  ALL_RIDERS: `${BASE_URL}/alerts_rider?page=1` as string,
};

export const REQUEST_TYPE = {
  GET: "GET" as string,
};
```

Types file is:

```
export const BASE_URL = "https://do-rider.cheetay.pk/alerts_rider?page=1";
export const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "token 6915953acf827475ce611bf14fd9820f51fbd454",
  },
};
export type RidersData = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  mobile_number: string;
  profile_image: null;
  last_alert: LastAlert;
};
type LastAlert = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  is_seen: boolean;
  description: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  rider: number;
};
```

Api middleware is following:

```
import axios from "axios";

interface Params {
  method: string;
  url: string;
  data?: any;
}

export function apiCaller({ method, url, data }: Params) {
  return axios({
    method,
    url,
    data,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "token 6915953acf827475ce611bf14fd9820f51fbd454",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((data) => data.data.results)
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

I am using this return axios apicaller through index file:

```
import { END_POINTS, REQUEST_TYPE } from "../../lib/constants";
import { RidersData } from "../../lib/types";
import { apiCaller } from "../apiCaller";

export function getAllRiders() {
  apiCaller({
    method: REQUEST_TYPE.GET,
    url: END_POINTS.ALL_RIDERS,
  });
}
```

And last of all I am using this index function in All Riders component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { RidersData, config, BASE_URL } from "../lib/types";
import { getAllRiders } from "../middleware/api";
const AllRiders = () => {
  const [apidata, setData] = useState<Array<RidersData>> ([]);
  const url = BASE_URL;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData =(): any => {
      try {
        const data =  getAllRiders();
        const allRiders = data as <Array<RidersData>>;
        setData(allRiders); 
        console.log(data, "========");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } 
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(apidata, "apidata");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> All riders </h1>
      <ul>
        {apidata?.map((rider) => (
          <li key={rider.id}>{rider.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllRiders;
```

And this is where error is occuring. the error is in useEffect and it says

```
Conversion of type 'void' to type '<Array>() => <RidersData>() => any' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extraneous tags (<>) in `const allRiders = data as <Array<RidersData>>;`

Should read
`const allRiders = data as Array<RidersData>;`
or simply
`const allRiders = data as RidersData[];`

Also, `getAllRiders()` returns a Promise. Either `await` it or use a `.then()`. So your `useEffect()` should look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getAllRiders();
        const allRiders = data as RidersData[];
        setData(allRiders); 
        console.log(data, "========");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } 
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Return the apiCaller() request in your getAllRiders() function:

```
export function getAllRiders() {
  return apiCaller({ // <--- added return
    method: REQUEST_TYPE.GET,
    url: END_POINTS.ALL_RIDERS,
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the effort but this is still showing an error saying

Comment: Conversion of type 'void' to type 'RidersData[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)                                                                                                                        on this line  const allRiders = data as RidersData[];

Comment: also it is showing an error on any return type of function saying:                                                      Type 'any' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.ts(1055)

Comment: Sorry was a little to quick, see updated answer. Removed the `async (): any` and also added a return in the function `getAllRiders()` so the response is properly propagated :)

Comment: man thank you very much I understood the problem :)